# Cannot change apple ID country/region

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id, accounts

I have bought an apple gift card while I was on a business trip in Germany. Now I can't roll back to the original country region - still have 15 Euro's in balance. Will it be possible to change the country of region to my original country? Seems apple ID won't accept my local credit card since it is not German.

Answer (score 1):

> Before you can delete your Apple ID or change your Apple ID country or region, you must spend any Apple ID balance. You also might have to wait for any pending refunds to process. If you have less balance than the cost of a single item, contact Apple Support.

[View your Apple ID balance](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202359)

[Change your Apple ID country or region](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389)