# App taken off my country's app store

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

Recently broke my iPhone 11 and upon trying to redownload apps after repairs, found one has been taken off the Australian app store. I use it lots, was actually the app I was using right before breaking the phone.

I'm hesitant to change regions to download it because I'm unsure of the consequences for other apps and settings. I have two movies, a bit of music on my Apple ID and plenty of apps. How much of this will remain untouched?

Probably sounds silly but I'd like to know if I can switch countries, download the app, and switch back with everything there or if it's worth creating an ID linked to a foreign country to  login and log back out with the app. Or if it's not worth it at all. I have any payment details needed to make the switch I'm sure.

Comment: Create a separate ID for the other country, switching countries is a pain and can have unexpected consequences (there is an older Q&A on this somewhere on the site, didn‘t find it yet).

Comment: Life was so much simpler when iTunes held all the apps. You could just restore from a local backup & be right back to where you left off. Now everything is OTA, you just get "App removed, tough luck sonny".

Comment: I've linked to a bunch of store/country related questions on top of your post, there are even more like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104190/mac-app-store-reuse-apps-after-changing-country?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/do-i-need-to-repurchase-apps-if-i-moved-countries/, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331829/cannot-change-app-store-country,  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366134/cannot-change-apple-id-country-region?rq=1

Comment: TL;DR: Changing countries has a lot of unexpected side effects and should be avoided if possible.